# Mount an ext hard drive and then delete the target mount folder

Tags: mount, fdisk, umount

I'm new to Ubuntu server and wanted to set up Plex on it.
I have an old laptop running Ubuntu server 16.04.1
I got an WD external hard drive with a movies folder.

Mount point: `/media/usb/plex_data/`

- I plugged the ext hard drive into the laptop and found the drive correct drive using "fdisk -l".
- I accidentally mount `sdb1` instead of `sdb2` as it should be on the mount point.
- I unmount it but I get an error, so I reboot and then delete the mount point and re create it.
- Now I did mount sdb2 correctly and managed to set up Plex
- Some days later I turn my laptop back again and try to mount the ext hard drive (which hasn't been used since). An error message says it wasn't unmated properly.
- Accidentally mount `sdb1` again
- Wanted to add a new movie to the ext hard drive, so I unmount it and plug it to my mac
- All files gone except for some hidden folders `.Trashes, .fsEventd, .spotlight`
- Freaking out thinking all files are gone! Now running EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard and currently it seems like it is able to find some files.

Q1: If an ext hard drive is mounted and you delete the mount point, will the data on the drive also be deleted?

Q2: I don't think I did delete the mount point of the mounted device, but is it possible that I might have deleted the data with wrong mount/unmount commands?

Comment: Deleting a mount point should recursively delete all files underneath it . Many things are possible, and many aren't, wrong commands are not unheard of, so you may have done something that caused data to be deleted.

Comment: Thanks. Then I guess I deleted the mount point while drive was still mounted...